# Data Manipulation / Dissecting

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to dissect some text within VBA, the two text examples I am trying to change are below:

*Original Data*

```
FAST CASH W5600Z *Scenario 1*
FAST CASH 5786Z *Scenario 2*
```

*Output Required*

```
D5600Z (Replacing the "W" with a "D") *Scenario 1*
D5786Z (Adding a "D" before the first numeric character) *Scenario 2*
```

This is the final part of my data manipulation and the code used to manipulate the data previously can be seen in the code below:

```
For Each b In wbRecFile.Sheets("Corrected Data1").Range("B1:B" & Lastrow)
    If b.Value <> "" Then     
        If UCase(Left(b.Value, 1)) = "W" Then b.Value = "D" & Right(b.Value, Len(b.Value) - 1)
        GoTo nextline
    End If

    If IsNumeric(Left(b.Value, 1)) Then b.Value = "D" & b.Value
    GoTo nextline
    End If

    End If 
nextline:     
Next b
```

Any suggestions on how I could achieve this within VBA would be much appreciated.  I am able to complete this task in excel formulas see below but I am trying my best to avoid this as a solution.

```
="D"&RIGHT(MID(Cell reference,FIND("W",cell reference),6),5)
```

Comment: Do you specifically require it in VBA or is VBA calling Excel Functions valid?  
It is way easier and saves you more time by simply using VBA to call Excel Functions.  For example `Range("B10").Formula = "=SUM(B4:B9)"`

Comment: Note that you would need a line break after both `Then` otherwise this is no valid syntax. If it is a typo please [edit] your question.

Comment: @ycx I could call excel functions, just unsure how to deal with the numeric element (Scenario two) or if the first scenario were to cause an error due to "W" not being present.

Comment: @peh thanks for editing the question :)

Comment: @SB999 you can do so by using the Excel Function `IFERROR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I have used the below code to resolve my issue.

```
Dim bText As String

Public Sub DisectText()
    Dim myString As String
    myString = bText
    Dim position As Long
    position = GetFirstNumeric(myString)
    If position > 0 Then
    bText = "D" & Mid(myString, position, 5)
    Else
    bText = ""
    End If
End Sub

Public Function GetFirstNumeric(ByVal value As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim bytValue() As Byte
    Dim lngRtnVal As Long
    bytValue = value
    For i = 0 To UBound(bytValue) Step 2
        Select Case bytValue(i)
            Case vbKey0 To vbKey9
                If bytValue(i + 1) = 0 Then
                    lngRtnVal = (i \ 2) + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
        End Select
    Next
    GetFirstNumeric = lngRtnVal
End Function
```